# Type error regarding the function isHullEdge, Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out the best way to complete the function isHullEdge.  I currently am trying to do it using a list comprehension, but I am getting a type error.  I'm still a beginner with Haskell so I'm having trouble understanding the stack trace to figure out what needs to be fixed.

```
type Edge a = (Point a, Point a)

-- Given an edge (that determines a line), say whether, as one moves along the
-- edge from its first to its second point, one must turn right (1) or left (-1)
-- to get to the point, or whether the point is on the line itself (0).
lineSide :: Real a => Edge a -> Point a -> a
lineSide ((e1x,e1y),(e2x,e2y)) (px,py) = signum ((px-e1x)*(e2y-e1y) - (e2x-e1x)*(py-e1y))

-- isHullEdge returns true just in case all points are on the same side of or
-- on the line determined by an edge.
isHullEdge :: Real a => [Point a] -> Edge a -> Bool
isHullEdge points edge | length points == 0 = True
                       | length [x | x <- points, lineSide edge x >= 0 || lineSide edge x <= 0] == length points = True
                       | otherwise = False
```

---

```
mod11PA.hs:54:50: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      isHullEdge :: forall a. Real a => [Point a] -> Edge a -> Bool
    at mod11PA.hs:52:15
* In the expression: lineSide edge x
  In a stmt of a list comprehension: c <- lineSide edge x
  In the first argument of `(==)', namely
    `[c | x <- points, c <- lineSide edge x]'
* Relevant bindings include
    x :: Point a (bound at mod11PA.hs:54:32)
    edge :: Edge a (bound at mod11PA.hs:53:19)
    points :: [Point a] (bound at mod11PA.hs:53:12)
    isHullEdge :: [Point a] -> Edge a -> Bool
      (bound at mod11PA.hs:53:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `length [ c | x <- points, c <- lineSide edge x]` instead of just `[ c | x <- points, c <- lineSide edge x]`. A list equaling `0` doesn't make any sense. Side note, checking if the length is zero is bad; it's an O(n) computation. Use `null` to check your list for emptiness, as it is O(1) for lists.

Using `all ((>=0) . lineSide edge) points` as your condition is a more idiomatic solution. You should only ever use list comprehensions when you actually want to use a list for something, not to do tests like these. Note that `all f xs = foldl (\a x -> if f x then a else False) True xs`

Comment: you are correct, but I realized that what I wrote doesnt make sense for what I'm trying to accomplish.  I want to iterate over all the x or points in the list "points" and for each point in the list call lineSide edge x and determine if the value returned is greater than or equal to or less than or equal to 0.  Thanks for your help.  You can check my edits above for what I changed.

Comment: It compiles now, but the method fails.

Comment: This is not a good use case for list comprehensions. I would use `all ((>=0) . lineSide edge) points` as the condition ([all from Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all))